# how to store text into database with html element tags

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

i am working on an asp.net application. in which i am storing something into database.before storing i am checking that is there any website written in it.If yes then the matches text should be stored with anchor tag just before that text. i am using following code to check link:

Regex regx = new Regex("http://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(txtWallComment.ToString());

foreach (Match match in mactches)
  {
      txtWallComment.InnerText = txtWallComment.InnerText.Replace(match.Value, "" + match.Value + "");
                    }

when i enter text  " I am searching http://www.xyz.com", it replace text and the replaced text becomes "I am searching http://www.xyz.com'>'.
But in the sql database it stores "I am searching a target=blank href=http://www.xyz.com>http://www.xyz.com/a>"...Here anchor tag is not stored into database>help me someone here.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea.  Markup generally does not belong in a relational database.

Comment: i want to add anchor tag just before any link found in a string and it the string should be stored into databse with the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better idea. I first encoded the string using server.HtmlEncode() just before storing into the database and decoded the string using server.HtmlDecode() during retrieval.

Now it is working as desired.